# Wix MSI - Using Listview instead of InstallDirDlg

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need to install a file, using MSI, in a specific location. The installation wizard must provide a list (I choosed the Listview control) with locations stored in registry. The installation will be performed into the choosen location from this list.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="MyInstallDirDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.InstallDirDlg_Title)">
                ...
                <Control Id="myRadioGroupLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="60" Width="290" Height="30" NoPrefix="yes" />
                <Control Id="myRadioGroup" Type="RadioButtonGroup" Property="buttonGroup" Width="320" Height="100" X="20" Y="100">
                    <RadioButtonGroup Property="buttonGroup">
                        <RadioButton Value="C:\abc" Text="C:\abc" Height="17" Width="320" X="0" Y="0" />
                        <RadioButton Value="C:\def" Text="C:\def" Height="17" Width="320" X="0" Y="40" />
                    </RadioButtonGroup>
                </Control>
                ...
                <!-- Control Id="FolderLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="60" Width="290" Height="30" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgFolderLabel)" />
                <Control Id="Folder" Type="PathEdit" X="20" Y="100" Width="320" Height="18" Property="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Indirect="yes" />
                <Control Id="ChangeFolder" Type="PushButton" X="20" Y="180" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgChange)" / -->
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

The is a copy of the original **InstallDirDlg.wxs**, where the ne wthings are these radio group related lines. How is possible to populate dynamically such a list with data (C:\abc, C:\def)? After selecting one item from it, how can I use it as TARGETDIR? I need the same functionality like the **ChangeFolder** button has.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what this design is doing? There might be an easier way.

Comment: I believe you should just be able to set the Property of the radio button group to TARGETDIR and this should set the value.